# Why should response caching be disabled for authenticated clients

Tags: caching

I am currently working on a website which provides a personalized timetable for each employee in a specific company, this timetable will internally update every five minutes. When opening the website you can just use a normal pager to look at all of the weeks.

At some point I noticed that the user behaviour shows, that people click between weeks a lot and visit the same page (of the pager) multiple times in even a minutes. I thought it would be a good idea to cache this individual pages for lets say 2,5 minutes.

Since this web app is powered by ASP.Net Core, I visited the [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/response?view=aspnetcore-3.0) about caching which states the following:

> Disable caching for content that contains information for authenticated clients. Caching should only be enabled for content that doesn't change based on a user's identity or whether a user is signed in.

I know that this is just a warning, but why is there the need of a warning? Is there any reason why this would be bad, besides the fact that specific data could be 'out dated'?

Comment: hmm..  I suggest you raise this discussion and inquiry using the feedback feature at the bottom of that documentation page.  For, we don't know what reasoning went into that documentation - not definitively.  And really, you should not be asking broad discussion orientated questions that are speculative and subjective (that can provide valid reasoning or otherwise).

Comment: Also, please be considerate to what tags you use.. this is not a `c#` related question, nor `asp.net-core` one.  You're asking what merits that warning about caching on a documentation site

Comment: There's some discussion on this in this issue: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/6836

Comment: @BrettCaswell I edited the tags, I forgot to remove them before publishing.

Comment: @Eilon Thanks for the link I will read it later though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer the question with the help of @Eilon, who linked me to [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/6836#issuecomment-451533228). Which provides a simple example. In a few words, it is all about, that a different authenticated user could possibly get a cached response which contains information about another authenticated user. Since this can be controlled and sometimes it won't even matter, it is only a warning in the MSDN.